# Need help on javascript & visual c++ communication and vice versa

Tags: javascript, visual-c++

Is there a way to invoke javascript methods from VC++ application and Vice versa without involving **html**?

Answer (score 2):

http://cplus.about.com/b/2009/01/26/using-javascript-in-your-c-applications.htm might start you off well

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, In fact I've gone through that website. But what I require is the communication between Visual C++ and java script, i.e through windows programming. Does the communication involve Webserver, http server etc??

Comment: What do you mean by communication? Are you referring to C++ invoking Javascript and returning the result back to C++?

For example, I'm currently using Java's javax.scripting API to allow intercommunications in the sense that I can invoke java methods from within javascript or invoke javascript from java.

Comment: @user570916, jerluc's answer does not require Webservers or http servers or html.  You communicate directly with V8 using your C++ code.